# Neptune2 [just came from Mars]

Tags: wpf

well , seriously guys i got sick of WPF errors and hard handling , look i got  many buttons are dsigned to represent rooms and i want to bind into a tooltip to get occupier name and  informations from database .
i cant find how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: You may want to change the title first.

Comment: You want to add tooltips to buttons in WPF? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 3):

1. Build a `RoomViewModel` class that exposes `Description`, `IsAvailable`, `OtherInformation`, and other properties and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  How you populate these properties is up to your application.
2. Build a `RoomsViewModel` class that exposes an `ObservableCollection<RoomViewModel>` named `Rooms`.
3. Create `DataTemplate`s for the `RoomViewModel` and `RoomsViewModel` classes (see below).
4. Create an instance of the `RoomsViewModel` class and populate its `Rooms` collection.
5. Create a `ContentPresenter` and set its `Content` property to the instance of your `RoomsViewModel` class.

Typical data templates might look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Type="{local:RoomsViewModel}">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Type="{local:RoomViewModel}">
   <Button 
      Margin="10"
      IsEnabled="{Binding IsAvailable}"
      ToolTip="{Binding OtherInformation}"
      Content="{Binding Description}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Future enhancements:

1. Try using a `UniformGrid` instead of a `WrapPanel`.
2. Read Josh Smith's article [Using RoutedCommands with a ViewModel in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx) and use the techniques described there to create a `ReserveRoomCommand` property on the `RoomViewModel`.  Set the `CommandBinding` in the `RoomViewModel` data template to `{Binding ReserveRoomCommand}`.  Note that once you do this, you'll remove the binding to `IsEnabled`, because the command binding will enable and disable the button automatically.
3. If you are going to need to reuse this UI, move the data templates and content presenter into a `UserControl`.

Comment: +1 for the amazing contrast of foolish question and serious answer.

Comment: Robert, this question could easily get deleted as well as closed. If so, please Ask & Answer the question again. It is useful enough to be saved.